# How do I create a modal popup like this using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get a modal popup almost like the ones you see when you send a message on Facebook or when you sign up to say the newsletter on www.gemvara.com in my own Ruby on Rails application.

The idea is someone signs up for a newsletter, and I give them a very friendly inline modal popup saying thanks for subscribing, etc.

How do I go about doing that with Ruby on Rails? Do I have to use ActionView? Do I write it in pure JavaScript and not bother doing it in Rails? How do you Rails experts suggest I do this the cleanest way possible using Rails 2.3.8.

I've found plugins that does this in jQuery, does that mean I should load jQuery AND Prototype which is Rails default javascript library of choice? Seems like a waste of network bandwidth to load both.

Answer (score 1):

Modal dialogs are accomplished via JavaScript.  Your rails app may provide the data, form, whatever that is displayed in the dialog, but you are doing a lot of the work in JavaScript.  I would recommend taking a look @ the jQuery UI project.  Here is a link directly to their modal dialog widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're not using jQuery, there is a rails plugin called Redbox, although I haven't used it in a while, but it also lets you create modals, and uses Prototype, in case you're using the default JS libs.